# VBA lookup discrepancies between a template and data

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a user access audit at work and I am trying to generate a simple tool where I can dump all the current user access into excel and it will check access against the access that they should have which is defined by a template.

The last 2 weeks have been spent generating Pivot Tables and manually checking for discrepancies but due to some recent changes I am required to re-check.

Scenario;

In Excel, I have an export of User ID’s, Roles and responsibilities (3 columns) whereby on new rows the only change in data is the responsibilities until the next user.  In the spreadsheet there is several thousand users, 300 different roles and of thousands of responsibilities.

On a second spreadsheet I have the templates for the actual roles and responsibilities that the roles should have (2 columns).  Or 3 columns if I add a column with an identifier instead of User ID, such as "Template"

I have a feeling that VBA can be used to generate a list of all the User ID's that do not match the actual roles. However I am open to other ideas but cannot use software that is not on our Whitelist.

i.e, provide a list of users with missing or extra responsibilities

It should also be noted that there are many users on the same roles in the first sheet but on the second sheet there is only one template per role.

I am a relative noob to VBA scripting and would really appreciate help/options that could make this task a simple process.

Please let me know what you have got to offer for advice?

Comment: You could try running through the export and remove all values from the second workbook where the username and role match the export, consequentially reducing the list to all roles incorrectly assigned to a user?

Answer (score 0):

Worksheet 1: Actual Usernames (Column A), Actual Roles (Column B).
Worksheet 2: Incorrect Usernames (Column A), Incorrect Roles (Column B).

This basic script runs grabs the value of the username and role present within Worksheet 1 and checks the values against both columns in Worksheet 2. If these don't match (if they're incorrect) then the incorrect row is removed from Worksheet (2).

You can change what happens when the criteria are met, such as change the background colour for invalid roles, etc.

```
Public Sub removeIncorrectRoles()
    For Each rngCell In Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row) 'Loops through usernames within the "correct" sheet.
        strUser = rngCell.Value 'Stores current username to avoid looking back to worksheet.
        strRole = rngCell.Offset(, 1).Value 'Stores current role to avoid looking back to worksheet.
        For Each rngCell2 In Worksheets(2).Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row) 'Loops through usernames within the "incorrect" sheet.
            If rngCell2.Value = strUser Then 'If the username in the incorrect page matches the correct name.
                If rngCell2.Offset(, 1).Value = strRole Then 'If the role on the "incorrect" page matches the actual role.
                'Do Nothing
                Else
                    rngCell2.EntireRow.Delete 'If the usernames match but the role doesn't then the line is removed.
                End If
            End If
        Next rngCell2 'Checks the next "incorrect" page value.
    Next rngCell 'Assigns the next "correct" page name and roll.
End Sub
```

Please bear in mind this is likely not very efficient, although should work. Let me know if you need anything.